# shift a viewport without redrawing

Tags: javascript, performance

To increase code performance I am trying to avoid redrawing every object inside a viewport as the view pans across the screen. My solution was to use the getImageData() and putImageData() methods to shift what was already drawn. Lust like redrawing everything, however, the frame rate plummets from 1,000 to 23. What I absolutely don't want to do is force game "window" down to 25 in-game squares. Is there any faster way to accomplish this?

```
function ViewPort() {
    .
    .
    .
    this.ReconcileViewPort = function() {
        .
        .
        .
        if (!(this.previousCenter.x == this.center.x && this.previousCenter.y == this.center.y)) {
            // shift the images on the canvases
            var data = canvasLayer0.getImageData(0, 0, canvasRaw.width, canvasRaw.height - this.bottomRibbonHeight);
            canvasLayer0.putImageData(data, this.previousCenter.x - this.center.x, this.previousCenter.y - this.center.y);

            data = canvasLayer1.getImageData(0, 0, canvasRaw.width, canvasRaw.height - this.bottomRibbonHeight);
            canvasLayer1.putImageData(data, this.previousCenter.x - this.center.x, this.previousCenter.y - this.center.y);

            data = canvasLayer2.getImageData(0, 0, canvasRaw.width, canvasRaw.height - this.bottomRibbonHeight);
            canvasLayer2.putImageData(data, this.previousCenter.x - this.center.x, this.previousCenter.y - this.center.y);

            data = canvasLayer3.getImageData(0, 0, canvasRaw.width, canvasRaw.height - this.bottomRibbonHeight);
            canvasLayer3.putImageData(data, this.previousCenter.x - this.center.x, this.previousCenter.y - this.center.y);

            // get ready to detect any movements
            this.previousCenter.x = this.center.x;
            this.previousCenter.y = this.center.y;
        }
    }
}
```